# What is the difference between $routeProvider and $stateProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Please explain the difference between `$routeProvider` and `$stateProvider` in AngularJS.

Which is best practice?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Both do the same work as they are used for routing purposes in SPA(Single Page Application).

### 1. Angular Routing - per [$routeProvider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

> URLs to controllers and views (HTML partials). It watches
>   $location.url() and tries to map the path to an existing route
>   definition.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Above tag will render the template from the `$routeProvider.when()` condition which you had mentioned in `.config` (configuration phase) of angular

**Limitations:-**

- The page can only contain single `ng-view` on page
- If your SPA has multiple small components on the page that you wanted to render based on some conditions, `$routeProvider` fails. (to achieve that, we need to use directives like `ng-include`, `ng-switch`, `ng-if`, `ng-show`, which looks bad to have them in SPA)
- You can not relate between two routes like parent and child relationship.
- You cannot show and hide a part of the view based on url pattern.

---

### 2. ui-router - per [$stateProvider docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

> AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows
>   you to organize the parts of your interface into a state machine.
>   UI-Router is organized around states, which may optionally have
>   routes, as well as other behavior, attached.

**Multiple & Named Views**

Another great feature is the ability to have multiple ui-views in a template.

While multiple parallel views are a powerful feature, you'll often be able to manage your interfaces more effectively by nesting your `view`s, and pairing those views with nested states.

**HTML**

```
<div ui-view>
    <div ui-view='header'></div>
    <div ui-view='content'></div>
    <div ui-view='footer'></div>
</div>
```

The majority of `ui-router`'s power is it can manage nested state & views.

**Pros**

- You can have multiple `ui-view` on single page
- Various views can be nested in each other and maintained by defining state in routing phase.
- We can have child & parent relationship here, simply like inheritance in state, also you could define sibling states.
- You could change the `ui-view="some"` of state just by using absolute routing using `@` with state name.
- Another way you could do relative routing is by using only `@` to change `ui-view="some"`. This will replace the `ui-view` rather than checking if it is nested or not.
- Here you could use `ui-sref` to create a `href` URL dynamically on the basis of `URL` mentioned in a state, also you could give a state params in the `json` format.

[**For more Information Angular ui-router**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

For better flexibility with various nested view with states, I'd prefer you to go for `ui-router`

Comment: can someone please show me and difference and equivalence of this routeprovider and stateprovider in codes?

Comment: @bleykFaust what do you mean by in the codes? the answer which I explained is in simple terms.. what part you don't understand?

Comment: @PankajParkar, I'm using routeprovider, I wonder how can I change that to stateprovider?

Comment: @bleykFaust then this is not answer to which you should look into.. this answer states difference `$stateProvider` & `$routeProvider`

Comment: Can it solve the need to pre-load a page using routes?

Comment: Preload a page using route means?

Comment: $routeProvider -> requires the ngRoute module (module by Angular) to be installed.
$stateProvider -> requires the ui.router module (3rd Party module) to be installed.

Answer (score 73):

Angular's own ng-Router takes `URLs` into consideration while routing, UI-Router takes `states` in addition to URLs.

> States are bound to named, nested and parallel views, allowing you to powerfully manage your application's interface.

While in ng-router, you have to be very careful about URLs when providing links via `<a href="">` tag, in UI-Router you have to only keep `state` in mind. You provide links like `<a ui-sref="">`. Note that even if you use `<a href="">` in UI-Router, just like you would do in ng-router, it will still work.

So, even if you decide to change your URL some day, your `state` will remain same and you need to change  URL only at `.config`.

While ngRouter can be used to make simple apps, UI-Router makes development much easier for complex apps. Here its [wiki.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

$route: This is used for deep-linking URLs to controllers and views (HTML partials) and watches $location.url() in order to map the path from an existing definition of route.

When we use ngRoute, the route is configured with $routeProvider and when we use ui-router, the route is configured with $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider.

```
<div ng-view></div>
    $routeProvider
        .when('/contact/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/core/contact/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactCtrl'
        });


<div ui-view>
    <div ui-view='abc'></div>
    <div ui-view='abc'></div>
   </div>
    $stateProvider
        .state("contact", {
            url: "/contact/",
            templateUrl: '/app/Aisel/Contact/views/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactCtrl'
        });
```