# Loading a Route within a Route in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have some HTML which looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="main">
    <div id="main">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('buildson', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.controller('main', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
});
```

And here is the Routing:

```
//ROUTING
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html'
        })
        .when('/courses', {
            templateUrl : 'views/coursesTeaching.html'
        });
});
```

Here is coursesTeaching.html

```
<div class="coursesList">
  [Display a list of courses here]
  <a href="#">Display Documentation</a>
</div>
```

And here is documentationWidget.html

```
Documentation Content is in this file
```

What I want to do is when they click on this link `<a href="#">Display Documentation</a>` It loads the documentationWidget.html content into the `<div class="documentationWidget"></div>` spot, I suppose it is a view within a view or a sub-route.  I can't do it with jQuery Ajax or anything because I want to be able to use Angular variables inside of the loaded html file.

Comment: Basically you need to switch to `ui-router`, you could find the difference between `ngRoute` & `ui-router` over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27645346/2435473

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `ui-router` as an alternative to `ngRoute`. This has good support for nested views amongst other things: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

This has also been discussed in more detail here: [**Difference between `ng-route` & ui-router**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27645346/2435473)

Answer (score 0):

I've been told you should use the third-party library [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for complex routing operations.