# How to use $routeProvider instead of $stateProvider in my angularJs webApp and which one is better to use?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJs for my webApp, but i used `$stateProvider` everywhere to define state.so now I want to use `$routeProvider` instead of `$stateProvider`.and how I change the route? is $location is good to change the path ?
This is my trial code with `$routeProvider`

```
angular.module("angular.states", [])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider'], function ($stateProvider, templateRoot, $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/login?username&message&error', {
            'templateUrl': '/templates/login.html',
            'controller': 'LoginController'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/logout', {
            'templateUrl': '/templates/logout.html',
            'controller': 'LogoutController'
        });
    })
    .controller('LoginController', function (UserService, $scope, $state, $stateParams, AuthFactory, $timeout, $location) {
        $scope.login = function (username, password) {
            UserService.login({
                'username': username,
                'password': password
            });
        };
    })
    .controller('LogoutController', function (UserService, $scope, $location) {
        $scope.logout = function () {
            UserService.logout({}, function () {
                $location.path("/login", {
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

I am not sure about `$routeProvider`, so please tell me how to use it

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27645346/2435473) which has all explanation you want, what are the pros and cons of both.?

Comment: sorry but what is pros and cons.? and please tell me how to implement `$routeProvider`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$stateProvider` instead of `$routeProvider`. because you can easily change your state using `$stateProvider`.
& if you use `$routeProvider` you need to use location, path, its url & all,
You cannot relate to routes with each other like who is parent and who is child.
so `$stateProvider` is always better to use.

Using `$stateProvider` :

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
        'url': '/login
        'templateUrl': '/templates/login.html',
        'controller': 'LoginController'
    });
```

here you can simply change your state with given `url` you dont need to locate the path.

Comment: is there any need to use `$location` ?

Comment: no, actually when you use `$stateProvider` it directly change the state no need to locate the path.