# How to migrate application from $routeProvider to $stateProvider in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on huge project, initially we used `$routeProvider`, but now we are thinking to use `$stateProvider`.

I have idea for both $routeProvider and $stateProvider.

I'm looking for best way to migrate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to do it manually. This is the  best way once can suggest.

Comment: Can I use both?

Answer (score 1):

for better flexibility with various nested view with states, I'd prefer you to go for ui-router

please go through the link attached

[$routeProvider VS $stateProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645202/what-is-the-difference-between-routeprovider-and-stateprovider-in-angularjs)

Comment: $stateprovider is used when you want the app to have different states like if you want jst a small section of a screen to be loaded at times instead of the entire screen, the go for State provider and the $state.go(url). 
$routeProider are commonly used for small projects. Mostly when you want the entire screen to be changed and redirected to a new one.While using the $state.go(url); for redirecting your screen, the real link of your screen won't change. It will just change the state and not the url of the page